# How do I program an Android App with Python?

Tags: android, python

I will be in charge of teaching a small group of middle school students how to program phone applications. After much research I found that Python might be the best way to go.

I am a website development senior at my university, but I have not used Python before.  I understand both ActionScript and Javascript and I think their logic might be beneficial for learning Python. For the web languages I am familiar with writing I use Sublime2, Dreamweaver, or Flash to code them.

So my questions are:

**Which program do I use to code Python?

How do I use the code created in Python to work on Android phones?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Python Programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185061/android-python-programming)

Comment: Btw. these questions can also easily be googled.

Comment: [STEP BY STEP GUIDE I was able to get Python 3 on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52140703/1689770)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many IDEs you can use for Python. You will have to find one that suits what you want to do. The official Python wiki has a [large list of IDEs](http://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments) and [editors](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonEditors) that you can use as a starting point.

However, keep in mind when you are teaching a class to not end up teaching the editor, but rather the language/concepts.

For Android, the only supported languages are Java and Kotlin. There is a [android-scripting](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) project that supports Python, however this is strictly experimental.

Comment: I was also looking at Java, however some people suggested that I don't take that path as Python is easier to learn and the kids would understand it better.

Comment: Python is easier (by far), but the issue is with Android. Perhaps start with [Python for kids](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781593274078.do).

Comment: Do you know of any good resources for Java and phones?

Comment: I found [the official guides](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) to be very friendly and easy to digest.

Answer (score 13):

I would suggest you to look at http://kivy.org/#home. It supports android, iphone, etc. Also if you are familliar with javascript as you said you can try great titanium accelerator, or some alternative to develop android app.

Comment: Thanks for the resource. I looked at Kivy earlier today, but I wasn't able to get it to properly work on my mac.  It said to drag the python file into the program and it should open, but it didn't. =\

Answer (score 2):

Old question, I know, but you can also check out [pygame subset for android](http://pygame.renpy.org/) which allows you to convert pygame applications to android.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Android scripting layer](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/).

Comment: This seems useful, how do I use it with a python file?

Comment: Have you read the introduction manual? http://android-scripting.googlecode.com/files/Practical_Android_Projects_Ch05_Introducing_SL4A.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Dr. python is a good ide/editor, but its simple to use. If your using linux, you can install it in the software center. I don't know how to install it on OSX/Windows