# The python3crystax recipe can only be built when using the CrystaX NDK. Exiting

Tags: macos, apk, kivy, buildozer

- Python Version: 3.6.3
- Kivy Version: v1.10.1.dev0, git-Unknown, 20180329
- pip Version: v9.0.3
- PC: MacOS Sierra v10.12.6
- CrystaX NDK: crystax-ndk-10.3.2

When running **"buildozer android debug"** to build android apk, I eventually got the error **"The python3crystax recipe can only be built when using the CrystaX NDK. Exiting."**

The log is as follow.

```
....
[INFO]:    python3crystax has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[ERROR]:   The python3crystax recipe can only be built when using the CrystaX NDK. Exiting.
b'\x1b[0m\r           working: SDL2_image-2.0.1.tar.gz                                    'b'\x1b[0m\r                                                                               \r'b'\x1b[0m\r           working: SDL2_mixer-2.0.1.tar.gz                                    'b'\x1b[0m\r                                                                               \r'b'\x1b[0m\r           working: SDL2_ttf-2.0.14.tar.gz                                     'b'\x1b[0m\r                                                                               \r'b'\x1b[0m\r           working: SDL2-2.0.4.tar.gz                                          'b'\x1b[0m\r                                                                               \r'b'\x1b[0m\r           working: six-1.9.0.tar.gz                                           'b'\x1b[0m\r                                                                               \r'b'\x1b[0m\r           working: master.zip                                                 'b'\x1b[0m\r                                                                               \r'b'\x1b[0m\r           working: 1.10.0.zip                                                 'b'\x1b[0m\r                                                                               \r'b'\x1b[0m\r           working: SDL2_image-2.0.1.tar.gz                                    'b'\x1b[0m\r                                                                               \r'b'\x1b[0m\r           working: SDL2_mixer-2.0.1.tar.gz                                    'b'\x1b[0m\r                                                                               \r'b'\x1b[0m\r           working: SDL2_ttf-2.0.14.tar.gz                                     'b'\x1b[0m\r                                                                               \r'b'\x1b[0m\r           working: SDL2-2.0.4.tar.gz                                          'b'\x1b[0m\r                                                                               \r'b'\x1b[0m\r           working: six-1.9.0.tar.gz                                           'b'\x1b[0m\r                                                                               \r'b'\x1b[0m\r           working: master.zip                                                 'b'\x1b[0m\r                                                                               \r'b'\x1b[0m\r           working: 1.10.0.zip                                                 'b'\x1b[0m\r                                                                               \r'# Command failed: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=unitconverter --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3crystax,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/Users/Sem/Dropbox/unit_converter/.buildozer/android/platform/build
```

What exactly is the problem?

I am suspecting CrystaX NDK is the problem, because I do not know which version of CrystaX NDK i should download from https://www.crystax.net/en/download. I eventually used "crystax-ndk-10.3.2-linux-x86_64.tar.xz"

Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: I have used Crystax NDK 10.3.2 with Python 3.5 and Buildozer. The other dependencies are: Cython 0.25.2 and JDK8 (JDK1.8.0_162).

Answer (score 1):

## buildozer.spec

Make sure the following lines are in your buildozer.spec file:

```
# (str) Android NDK version to use
android.ndk = 10.3.2
...
# (str) Android NDK directory
android.ndk_path = /opt/crystax-ndk-10.3.2
```

## JAVA Version

Use JDK8 or jdk1.8.0_162

[Welcome to Buildozer’s documentation!](http://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

> Currently, Buildozer supports packaging for:
>
> Android: via Python for Android. You must have a Linux or OSX computer
>   to be able to compile for Android.

[Build options » Python3 » Crystax NDK](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/buildoptions/)

> Use the ***CrystaX NDK 10.3.0 or higher*** when building with Python3.
>
> Warning
>
> Python3 support is experimental, and some of these details may change
>   as it is improved and fully stabilised.

Comment: Were you able to get a kivy app running?

Comment: Yes. Now, I usually use Buildozer with Python 2 because the build size is smaller, and not all recipes are available for Python 3.

Comment: [I got Python 3.5 working too with these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52140703/1689770)