# How can I write an Android app in Python?

Tags: android, python

I want to write an Android app in Python, something along the lines of converting a .py file to an APK.

Comment: Please post in English only

Comment: @BhargavRao I translated.

Answer (score 2):

A few points: first, there's actually a lot more to an APK than just zipping up bytecode (e.g. application manifest, resources, etc.), so it doesn't really make sense to talk about "converting" a Python file to an APK.

Secondly, I wouldn't encourage this. I'd *strongly* encourage using Xamarin Forms, Cordova, Java, or Xamarin.Android instead. The advantage of Xamarin Forms or Cordova is that you can create cross-platform applications with a single code-base. In terms of platform-specific development, Xamarin.Android and Java both have very good tool support (through Android Studio and Visual Studio).

With that said, there's an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319018/how-do-i-program-an-android-app-with-python) you can use if you insist on using Python. There are a number of frameworks available as well, such as [QPython](http://qpython.com/) and [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home) (which is designed for cross-platform apps, analogous to Xamarin Forms for C# and Cordova for JavaScript/html5).

Comment: I would like to advocate that you also take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49955489/android-app-completely-in-python/50595676#50595676