# How to develop Android app completely using python?

Tags: android, python

I would like to develop a (rather simple) android app to be distributed via Play Store. I would like to do so completely in python. However, the online research hasn't quite enlightened me: most comments are either outdated (>1 year old, and I feel there might be better integration of python since then) or they talk about *running python* in android (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40326178/how-can-i-write-an-android-app-in-python)).

Therefore, I'm looking for information regarding the questions:

- is it feasible to develop an App completely in python - and what are the tools to do so? (Is e.g. Kivy recommendable?)
- if so: what are the best software environments to implement this? (I unsuccessfully tried using Android Studio but couldn't figure out a way to run python code there.)

I'm quite new to app development and would highly appreciate any leads of doing this in python rather than in Jave etc., which I don't know yet.

Comment: in the past, i used kivy and their buildozer program. they have documentation here https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html

Comment: Natively you have to use either Java or Kotlin, however as others have pointed out there are 3rd party "app-builders" or frameworks you can use with python like PyMob or Kivy.

Comment: I created an Android game that is completely developed in Python using Kivy. It is called CoinTex available here at Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=coin.tex.cointexreactfast. The source code of the game is available here at GitHub: https://github.com/ahmedfgad/CoinTex. I also wrote a book that will be published thus year for building Android apps using Python. It is titled "Building Android Apps in Python Using Kivy with Android Studio: With Pyjnius, Plyer, and Buildozer Ahmed Fawzy Gad"  available here at Amazon: https://www.amazon.com/dp/1484250303.

Comment: Can't post an answer, but [here seems to be a solution](https://www.pycon.it/conference/talks/developing-android-apps-completely-in-python): *Different technologies will be demonstrated, including PySide-based QML GUIs using the Necessitas Qt port and the Py4A/SL4A-based approach, which can be combined with Android’s WebKit and re-use Python web frameworks.*

Comment: I do not understand why this question was closed. It should imho be reopened.

Comment: The two questions (Can you recommend Kivy; what IDE to recommend) are both software recommendation questions rather than about solving a concrete issue. Needs to be more specific to say whether a solution fits. A good overview can be found here otherwise: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Android

Answer (score 177, accepted):

To answer your first question: **yes it is feasible to develop an android application in pure python**, in order to achieve this I suggest you use [BeeWare](https://pybee.org), which is just a **suite of python tools**, that work together very well and they enable you to develop platform native applications in python.

checkout [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xezYYBL7nk0&t) by the creator of BeeWare that perfectly explains and demonstrates it's application

### How it works

Android's preferred language of implementation is Java - so if you want to write an Android application in Python, you need to have a way to run your Python code on a Java Virtual Machine. This is what **VOC** does. [VOC](https://pybee.org/project/projects/bridges/voc) is a transpiler - it takes Python source code, compiles it to CPython Bytecode, and then transpiles that bytecode into Java-compatible bytecode. The end result is that your Python source code files are compiled directly to a Java .class file, which can be packaged into an Android application.

VOC also allows you to access native Java objects as if they were Python objects, implement Java interfaces with Python classes, and subclass Java classes with Python classes. Using this, you can write an Android application directly against the native Android APIs.

Once you've written your native Android application, you can use [Briefcase](https://pybee.org/project/projects/tools/briefcase) to package your Python code as an Android application.

**Briefcase** is a tool for converting a Python project into a standalone native application. You can package projects for:

- Mac
- Windows
- Linux
- iPhone/iPad
- Android
- AppleTV
- tvOS.

You can check This native Android [Tic Tac Toe app](https://github.com/eliasdorneles/tictactoe-voc) written in Python, using the BeeWare suite. on GitHub

in addition to the BeeWare tools, you'll need to have a JDK and Android SDK installed to test run your application.

and to answer your second question: a good environment can be anything you are comfortable with be it a text editor and a command line, or an IDE, if you're looking for a good python IDE I would suggest you try [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), it has  a community edition which is free, and it has a similar environment as android studio, due to to the fact that were made by the same company.

I hope this has been helpful

Comment: Is it just me, or has VOC been abandoned?

Comment: this is a dead end (Last time I checked it out: Dec. 2018).  One or more components in this overly complex solution isn't functioning anymore, or can't keep itself up to date.

Comment: Just an update to this for 2019, but Kotlin is now the preferred language for Android development.

Comment: @BerryTsakala can you elaborate? So do you think BeeWare solutions will be dead in a near future (I want to avoid investing time on it, then...)?

Comment: @Basj I'd like to say that Beeware will definitely be around for a while, because just by taking a look at its GitHub account you will find that it is being actively developed, and if you head over to the Gitter channel, you can always reach the whole team, especially Dr Russell (freakyboy) the creator, and the community is quite friendly, and also there was a very recent tweet (Sep 26 2019) tweet from their official account announcing that they received an education grant from the Python software foundation. I think it would be worth your time, especially if you like python as a language

Comment: BeeWare does not seem to support Android (Java) at this stage in any event.

Comment: but beeware does not support image and other widgets

Comment: hi @SearchImtiyaz from toga documentation you can use [ImageView](https://toga.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/widgets/imageview.html)     

you can also check out the full [Toga Reference](https://toga.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/index.html) for list of available widgets

Answer (score 20):

You could try [BeeWare](https://pybee.org) - as described on their website:

> Write your apps in Python and release them on iOS, Android, Windows, MacOS, Linux, Web, and tvOS using rich, native user interfaces. One codebase. Multiple apps.

Gives you want you want now to write Android Apps in Python, plus has the advantage that you won't need to learn yet another framework in future if you end up also wanting to do something on one of the other listed platforms.

Here's the [Tutorial for Android Apps](https://pybee.org/project/using/android-app/).

Comment: Did you build an app yourself with BeeWare ?

Answer (score 19):

**Android, Python !**

When I saw these two keywords together in your question, [Kivy](https://kivy.org/) is the one which came to my mind first.

[image: Kivy logo]

Before coming to native Android development in Java using Android Studio, I had tried [Kivy](https://kivy.org/). It just awesome. Here are a few advantage I could find out.

**Simple to use**

With a python basics, you won't have trouble learning it.

**Good community**

It's well documented and has a great, active community.

**Cross platform.**

You can develop thing for Android, iOS, Windows, Linux and even Raspberry Pi with this single framework.
Open source.

**It is a free software**

At least few of it's (Cross platform) competitors want you to pay a fee if you want a commercial license.

**Accelerated graphics support**

[Kivy](https://kivy.org/)'s graphics engine build over OpenGL ES 2 makes it suitable for softwares which require fast graphics rendering such as games.

Now coming into the next part of question, you can't use Android Studio IDE for Kivy. [Here](https://kivy.org/docs/gettingstarted/installation.html) is a detailed guide for setting up the development environment.

Comment: Windows support is lagging way behind production standards (or even hobbyist standard).
Plus, half of the world can't use it due to lack for RTL support.

Comment: Why did you leave Kivy and change it to native development tools? You suggests that it has some disadvantages.

Comment: Plus Google Collab with these settings: https://towardsdatascience.com/3-ways-to-convert-python-app-into-apk-77f4c9cd55af. It's fast, easy and great!

Answer (score 17):

There are two primary contenders for python apps on Android

## Chaquopy

https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/

This integrates with the Android build system, it provides a Python API for all android features. To quote the site "The complete Android API and user interface toolkit are directly at your disposal."

## Beeware (Toga widget toolkit)

https://pybee.org/

This provides a multi target transpiler, supports many targets such as Android and iOS. It uses a generic widget toolkit (toga) that maps to the host interface calls.

## Which One?

Both are active projects and their github accounts shows a fair amount of recent activity.

Beeware Toga like all widget libraries is good for getting the basics out to multiple platforms. If you have basic designs, and a desire to expand to other platforms this should work out well for you.

On the other hand, Chaquopy is a much more precise in its mapping of the python API to Android. It also allows you to mix in Java, useful if you want to use existing code from other resources. If you have strict design targets, and predominantly want to target Android this is a much better resource.