# Python Android Development

Tags: android, python, python-3.x

I'm trying to run a simple hello world app as a start of python in android,im an intermediate in python,never tried python in android but i want to run it in my phone, but i've tried, researched, i've installed kivy, and all its requirements in its original website, my main error is down below, im on windows 10, and i try this apt,sudo and dpkg thing none of them are recognized as an internal or external command(i do these in command prompt, should i not?),i have the buildozer.spec file in lib but couldnt find a way to edit, i've also tried other ways im really stuck here, my android version is 5.0.1 if that helps, please help im stuck.

```
C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib>buildozer android debug deploy run
I Check configuration tokens
[91m[1mBuildozer is running as root![0m
[91mThis is [1mnot[0m [91mrecommended, and may lead to problems 
later.[0m
Are you sure you want to continue [y/n]? y
Unknown command/target android_old
```

Comment: ... sudo and apt are for linux ...

Comment: Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localized guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: This may help: [android-app-completely-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49955489/android-app-completely-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should download the kivy virtual machine at https://kivy.org/#download (It's at the bottom). Import the machine into virtualbox. If you don't have virtualbox installed, you can download it at https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads. Get your application files into the virtual machine, and run `buildozer init` in your project directory. Edit the buildozer.spec file, and run `buildozer -v android debug`.

Worked for me. Hopes this helps. :)