# Why use Java/Kotlin instead Python on Android?

Tags: java, python, android, kotlin

I'm novice. That's why I can't understand the essential difference between using Java/Kotlin or using Python with its numerous modules for Android application development. Is there a good reason that makes Java/Kotlin better choice? Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Google** is the commercial marketer of Android and they currently support **Java** and **Kotlin** as official language for Android Development. That's why everybody prefer **Java** and **Kotlin**.

There are some other languages [mentioned here](https://dzone.com/articles/most-used-programming-languages-for-android-app-de), that are also use for Android Development such as **C#(Unity and Xamarin)**.

Comment: More exactly the Open Handset Alliance is the "owner" of Android.

Comment: It looks much more understandable now. Thank you.

Comment: @ЭдуартКотов, Welcome. Mark answer accepted and upvote so that other can found it helpful

Comment: Sorry. I can't upvote because my reputation score is low. I am new here

Answer (score 1):

If you read [Application Fundamentals](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals) you will notice -

> Android apps can be written using Kotlin, Java, and C++ languages. The
>   Android SDK tools compile your code along with any data and resource
>   files into an APK, an Android package, which is an archive file with
>   an .apk suffix. One APK file contains all the contents of an Android
>   app and is the file that Android-powered devices use to install the
>   app.

So, Kotlin, Java, and C++ are the officially supported languages. Using any languages other than them will be a hacky process. Basically, android apps run in a virtual machine. If you want to build apps with python then you have to have a way to convert python code into byte code that the VM understands. I am afraid there is official support for this kind of conversion like Kotlin.

Although [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50595676/5465447) shows how you can develop android apps using python but you would probably not consider using python over Java/Kotlin for the following two primary reasons:

1. Official support.
2. Huge Java/Kotlin community.

Comment: I've got a lot of more information about what is going on due to your answer. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

**Java** and **Kotlin** are the official language of Android SDK.
That's why all use these. On the other way, python use to make cross platfrom application.