# How to write Python on android studio?

Tags: python, android-studio

I want to make an android app with python so,
Can I use **python** on **android studio**? 
And if so how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android app completely in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49955489/android-app-completely-in-python)

Comment: Take a look at this article: https://realpython.com/mobile-app-kivy-python/

Comment: There's no way, compilers are completely different

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure there's no way to run python in Android studio, someone correct me if Im wrong. But a similar IDE to it for python is Pycharm.

As for making an app in python there's a few frameworks to make apps in Python, one of the most popular being [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home). There's a ton of tutorials on YouTube on it.

Enjoy! :)