# Can I write native iPhone, Android, Windows, Blackberry apps using Python?

Tags: android, python, ios, blackberry, windows-mobile

Is possible to develop Android and iOS mobile applications in Python? I am a newcomer in mobile applications and want to develop mobile applications in Python.

Comment: Already discussed in [previous thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7950875/2345913). check for reference

Comment: Possibly, but it wouldn't be "native".

Answer (score 21):

Yes you can use [kivy](http://kivy.org/#home)

This is a **nice cross platform python framework** which works for Android, Win7, Linux, Mac. iOS is possibile but very trivial as Apple doesn't allow scripting.

And for Android Google provides something called [ASE](http://google-opensource.blogspot.in/2009/06/introducing-android-scripting.html) (Android Scripting Environment) which allows scripting languages (Python included) to run on Android. More details here

For iOS Python development would be to embed a Python interpreter into you app and distribute your Python script with it (so to play nicely with Apple rules). In this case your Python application would be a Python interpreter which is packaged with your script and runs it automatically. As I've said - it ain't pretty
You can check details [Here](http://www.saurik.com/id/5)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: but for android  at the end of application development ,testing will only allow in android(java)  or unit testing (python) ?

Comment: A better way is to compile down python code top C using cython and use it as a library. link to the C code from Obj-C

Comment: He said *native* applications.

Answer (score 5):

Not out of the box. The final product needs to be compiled (iOS) or in bytecode (Android). Since it may be possible to convert Python code to Objective-C or something in between it might be possible.

See [Kivy](http://kivy.org/) — the [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7950875/2345913) referenced it. This allows you to write you app in Python but probably uses a common wrapper (that Kivy provides) to run Python.

Please note that code written in Objective-C (iOS) or Java (Android) will always be faster than middle-ware like Kivy or Phonegap. Unless the one developing is very bad at writing any of those native languages....