# Is it possible to create ANDROID app with python?

Tags: android, python

I know nothing about Android n Python but I am giving my best effort to learn python. What can I do for betterment?

Comment: Can't say about android apps using python(although have heard something about jython) but, python is a major language extensively used in Machine Learning and Data Science. So, its great if you learn this language properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I write native iPhone, android , windows ,blackberry apps using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382246/can-i-write-native-iphone-android-windows-blackberry-apps-using-python)

Comment: why to do that? why not to use Java?

Comment: You should search before ask! It is full of answers to this question. There're frameworks to [novel engines](https://www.renpy.org/), [games](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-make-an-Android-app-with-Python) and even simple application (see the duplicate).

Comment: I think that it is bad idea to do that in Python. Main reason is that you can't find support if you run into problems (and you will for sure) because (almost) nobody does that, and (almost) nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 3):

There's [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home), a python framework for developing cross-platform apps.
You could give it a try, but like others are saying, if you want to learn Android development, you should be learning Java.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to learn Python, Android Studio / Android Applications are not what you need.

Just to answer the question: 
   Android Applications can be written using SDK (java) or NDK (C/C++)

Comment: That's not true, see the duplicates questions

Comment: Also in Javascript/HTML (cordova), C#(Xamarin), Object Pascal (Delphi XE), and almost all other existing languages.

Comment: If he is trying to learn Python...won't be a good start for him..
About the 2nd part of my answer, honnestly I did not know about that, also not sure it is very used

Comment: You must attend to the question, and the question is "Python could be used to create applications?"

Comment: I agree that this doesn't answer the question. it sounds like Q: *I have a shovel. Can I chop trees with it?* A: *Shovel is not what you need to chop trees. Trees can be cut using Axe.*. ok, but still `Can I chop trees with it?` there is no *answer* in your answer