# What is Python android scripting limitations?

Tags: android, python, scripting

I had Read that making android apps in possible using Python
but it is not powerful as Java
my question is: what are the limitations of python Android scripting
can I do with python an android app that can monition-send-receive SMS without the user doing anything ?

I want to make an app that when it see a keyword in a SMS it get the current GPS location and send it through another SMS to the number the first message is received from.
it is a basic anti theft so I can trace my phone if it is stolen
and all the process is hidden without the user (theft)  knowing anything or hearing an sms sound.
PS: i know there is many advanced anti theft on the market but i want to make my own

is making that simple app possible in python ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Python Programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185061/android-python-programming)

Comment: no it is not duplicate, im asking for the sms thing which is not mentioned there